# Any в hashmap kotlin

Tags: kotlin, java-hashmap

Есть класс

```
data class Test(
    var fields: HashMap<String, Any>?
) {
    constructor(name: String?) : this(
       fields = if (name != null ) hashMapOf("IVANOV" to name) else null
    )
}
```

При создании `Test("IVAN")`
получаю ошибку

`Error:(17, 46) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.collections.HashMap<String, String> /* = java.util.HashMap<String, String> */ but kotlin.collections.HashMap<String, Any>? /* = java.util.HashMap<String, Any>? */ was expected`
в чем тут проблема?
если проделать такое в вызове обычного метода - все хорошо,но в конструкторе - нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо был баг в компиляторе, в kotlin 1.4 не воспроизводится https://pl.kotl.in/BGpzsGMke

В версиях ниже нужно явно указать типы мапы

```
fields = if (name != null ) hashMapOf<String, Any>("IVANOV" to name) else null
```

Иначе она получается `HashMap<String, String>`, которую нельзя присвоить в `HashMap<String, Any>` (Инвариантность)

Comment: Спасибо большое!